# Javascript Show Hide input not working the second time bootstrap modal is loaded

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a JavaScript code to hide and show an upload input using a checkbox inside a bootstrap modal, it is working when modal is fired up the first time, but on the second i open the modal, and click on the checkbox to show the upload input, it shows but then it automatically hides it.

```
$('.modal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {        
    $(".upload_file").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".upload_file").slideToggle();    
    });

       //jquery validation goes here...
});
```

What am i missing here, hope you guys can help. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating multiple click events, every time you open the modal it creates a new one.

Change

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".upload_file").slideToggle();    
});
```

to

```
$('.show_hide').off('click').on('click', function(){
    $(".upload_file").slideToggle();    
});
```

This will kill the first click event, and then rebind it.

Alternatively you could move the binding for the click event out of the modal initialisation so it only gets called once.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click','.show_hide',function(){
    $(".upload_file").slideToggle();    
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: if your hide and show model add using ajax then direct on click event is not work so you can use like this.you can use body or html or parent div if it's not affected for ajax.